# How to configure zshell's terminal to start a new line

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I want to change my terminal from:

```
user@name-Air ~ % <My command>
```

to something like

```
user@name-Air ~ %
<My command>
```

Basically I want my command to start on a new line.

Comment: You need to create a prompt https://www.makeuseof.com/customize-zsh-prompt-macos-terminal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code in your `~/.zshrc` will begin the input on the next line:

```
PS1='%* %D %%
'
```

that is, simply placing an explicit newline at the end of the prompt formatter.

As example implementation using `echo`:

```
~ %echo "PS1='%* %D %%\n'" >> ~/.zshrc
~ %zsh
20:24:04 23-08-05 %
ls -lah /etc
```

Comment: I would write it like `PS1=$'%* %D %%\n'` to make the newline explicit but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @KurtisRader : I had even expected, that `$' ... '` would be mandatory here. At least the _zshmisc_ man-page (section _EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES_)  does not document the expansion of \n , and I'm surprised that the suggestion in this answer works. I wonder where is this documented...

Comment: @user1934428 We guess the formatter consumes everything else and carries what’s left into printf which are the whitespaces that include newlines.

Comment: The guess makes sense, I just prefer documented behaviour over guessing :-( The zsh man-pages are convoluted, and I would not be surprised, if this is indeed documented somewhere in an obscure corner where nobody is looking ...

Comment: @user1934428 prompt.c handles newline and further ensures that a newline at the end of a full-terminal-width prompt line doesn’t get doubly incremented. https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-87/zsh/Src/prompt.c

Comment: @user1934428 in `utils.c` the function `printprompt4()` expands the prompt and passes the result to `fprintf()`  https://opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-87/zsh/Src/utils.c

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking this up. Now let's hope that this "implemented, but undocumented feature" is also present in the other zsh ports (and not only Apple) - after all, Apple a few some adaptions to zsh -, and also that this feature doesn't get silently removed one day. I just feel that using the approach suggested by KurtisRader, we can rely on what is officially in the docs, and not on what just happens to be in the code of a particular zsh version....

Comment: @user1934428 Here it seems that `echo` is being used to recognise "\n" as a `<newline>`

Comment: @rowboat: I see. I missed it that this answer uses a dynamic `echo` to **append** something to .zshrc, instead of advising the use of a proper text editor, and therefore the newline is physically inside the single quotes. I don't think this is a good idea, because it may your .zshrc left with several definitions for PS1, and a single quoted string spanning two lines is also not exactly helpful for maintenance. I think I will, now that I understand the problem, provide my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are defining the prompt in one of the zsh startup files, you can also modify it. If you don't supply your own prompt definition, zsh uses as a default `%m%#` . This is described in the section *PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL* in the zsh-man-page; the variable which is relevant for the prompt is `PS1`. The most common file to put a definition for `PS1` is your ~/.zshrc, because this is a startup file for interactive shell.

Hence you have to edit this file and find the current definition for `PS1` (if there is none, you either have a definition in one of the other zsh startup files, in which case I recommend moving them over, or you don't have one and therefore are using the default value).

Let's say that you have in your present .zshrc the definition

```
PS1='%m%# '
```

which just is equivalent to the default one. If you want to have a newline after the prompt, just redefine it to

```
PS1=$'%m%#\n'
```

The `$'...'` constructs simply enables the interpretation of \n in single-quoted strings as a newline character. As has been pointed out in various comments in this thread, the leading `$` is not strictly necessary here, because the prompting meachanism happens to be written so that \n is understood correctly.

However, this behavioud does not seem to be explicitly defined in the zsh man-page, while the `$'...'` construct **is** defined. Therefore I suggest to use this construct to be on the safe side.

After changing your .zshrc in this way, every new interactive zsh will see this prompt definition.